# click function not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong with this Javascript code? I can't figure it out..................................................................................

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my-button").click(function(button){
        $("#my-button").html("Clicked!");
        });
    });

</script>

<button id="my-button">Not clicked</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there a console error? May be Jquery is not included? If it still does not work, show your html code, Check this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/JEcDm

Comment: is your button element in DOM at time you declare your event handler? BTW, if you have errors in console it could be clever to let us know

Comment: May be you're attach event on link?

Comment: If you're add event to a link, you need add `return false`

Comment: There are no console errors at all.

Comment: Add `http` to your script src: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` -- I'm assuming this isn't on a web server.

Comment: The HTML doesn't update

Comment: `<script>` replace with `<script type="text/javascript">` and put in between `<head>` tags

Comment: @Winston: Neither of those suggestions is required.

Comment: @tymeJV I already have that?

Comment: No, add the `http:` in front of the `//`

Comment: Need replace `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js` to `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js` and it will work, I'm checked now

Answer (score 4):

Add `http:` in front of your jQuery URL. If you are simply opening this page locally, it is probably searching for `file://` instead of `http://`. Change to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't there be an error in the console then when '$' is called?

Comment: @jesus.tesh -- why would there be an error?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear - if your suggestion was the fix, that would mean the OP would have gotten an error before applying your fix. It does behave that way when working form a local file, so you are correct, but the OP stated there is no console error.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you haven't attached the jQuery library - this happens automatically in jsFiddle.

**Edited**: Automatically, in that you only have to select the jQuery library in the panel on the left in jsFiddle.

Comment: <<this happens automatically in jsFiddle>> no, you need to set here too

Comment: it does not happen automatically in fiddle.. You have to select jquery explicitly. .

Comment: Yes, you have to select it in the panel on the left, but when you make a page from the code you have to do this yourself - to type the code that attaches the library.